# KeyListener does not work when exported

Tags: java, swing, file, export, keylistener

I just coded a Java program (code down below). It's meant to be a screensaver. When I run the code in eclipse everything works perfectly, as soon as a key is clicked or the mouse is clicked the program gets closed. But when I export it as a .jar file, this function sometimes works, but most of the time it doesn't?! Why is that?

```
public class fullscreen extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

public fullscreen() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

    BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Create a new blank cursor.
    Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
        cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");



    BorderLayout bL = new BorderLayout();
    String text = new String();

    // create JFrame
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myframe.setUndecorated(true);
    myframe.setResizable(false);
    myframe.setLayout(bL);  
    myframe.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    myframe.setBackground(new Color(144,132,118));
    myframe.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(144,132,118));
    myframe.validate();
    myframe.setVisible(true);
    // Set the blank cursor to the JFrame.
    myframe.getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);
    fullscreen fs = new fullscreen();
    fs.setOpaque(false);

    myframe.getContentPane().add(fs);
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(myframe);

    //set font and size
    Font myfont = new Font("Space Colony", Font.PLAIN, 40);


    //get temp path and add the customer.txt
    String tempPath = new String(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    String finalPath = tempPath += "customer.txt";

    System.out.println(finalPath);

    //Dateipfad ersetzen mit dem Pfad, wo die txt Datei liegt.
    File aFile = new File(finalPath);


    //create Label and add to JFrame
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Loading Text...");
    label.setForeground(Color.white);
    label.setFont(myfont);
    label.setBackground(Color.black);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    myframe.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    try{ Scanner scanner = new Scanner(aFile);
    text = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
    label.setText("Herzlich Willkommen " + text + "!");
    scanner.close();
}catch (Exception e){

     label.setText("Herzlich Willkommen!");
}

}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("dragged");
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tempPath = new String(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    String finalPath = tempPath += "customer.txt";

    File filledFile = new File(finalPath);
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filledFile);
        writer.print("");
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("geleert");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.print("Hier");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("klick!");
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String tempPath = new String(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    String finalPath = tempPath += "customer.txt";


    File filledFile = new File(finalPath);
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filledFile);
        writer.print("");
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("geleert");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.print("Hier");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.exit(0);
}



@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("typed");
}


}
```

Comment: [Oracle Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)

Comment: I normally don't code in java, just had to for this project.. so can you maybe give a short explanation on why I have that problem and maybe a solution?

Comment: Do the languages you code with all use all-left justified code? If so, they must be difficult to read, as difficult as your current code is to read. Consider editing your post so that your code conforms to standards, including use of indentations, avoidance of over use of empty lines, etc. so that we can read and understand it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just copied the code from a mail, so maybe that's why the format is kinda weird.. I thought maybe someone also had this problem, should be something with the key listener , either the registration of it or the key listener methods? Or maybe I do something wrong when I export it? When I get home I will change the code to the original one

Comment: Most Swing experts avoid use of KeyListeners in favor of key bindings where it is appropriate. You may have other problems in that it looks like you're doing file I/O and when doing this from a Jar you must take care that you're doing it correctly. You can't read files inside of a jar (you can read "resources") and you can't write a file into a jar, not without doing gymnastics. So you'd best make sure that you're using correct paths relative to the user's working directory or "user.dir".

Comment: I just edited the code (I know, still some empty lines).. Can you maybe show me an example or tell me how I can fix that? Would be very nice!! I think I need to export as a .jar file and then wrap it with something like Launcher4j into an .exe and then to .scr to make it a screensaver right?

Comment: Just to make it clear, I need to access a .txt that lies in the temp directory, this file will be there 100%. I need to read whats inside that file and when the program ends, it needs to delete anything inside.. So how can I achieve that without the file I/O?? The .txt is not inside my java project, cause it's edited by another program someone else inside my company is programing.

Comment: And actually the reading or writing works perfectly, it's just the exit when a key is pressed that does not work

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the very first line! Actually I don't know why that makes a huge difference, but it works perfectly now. 
So now I have:

```
public class fullscreen extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

public fullscreen() {
addMouseListener(this);
addMouseMotionListener(this);
addKeyListener(this);
setFocusable(true);
}
```

and of course change

```
JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
```

to:

```
fullscreen myframe = new fullscreen();
```

and delete the parts where fullscreen was a Panel added to the Frame.